# Given a normal $A_{n\times n}$ matrix, then $\lVert A^*v \rVert = \lVert Av\rVert$ and $\langle Av,v\rangle = \langle A^*v,v\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let  a normal $A_{n\times n}\in \mathbb C^n $ matrix, then:
>
> 1. $\forall v \in \mathbb C^n:\lVert A^*v \rVert = \lVert Av\rVert $
> 2. $\forall v \in \mathbb C^n : \langle Av,v\rangle = \langle A^*v,v\rangle$

1. I thought to maybe use the Pythagorean theorem but it doesn't help, also the eigenvalues of the two matrices can be different so how could the lengths be the same? for example $A^*v = kv,Av = rv, r\neq k$ then $\lVert kv \rVert = \lVert rv\rVert $?
2. we have $\langle Av,v\rangle = \langle A^*v,v\rangle \Rightarrow \langle Av-A^*v,v\rangle = 0$, the eigenvalues of $A,A^*$ can be different so $Av-A^*v \neq 0$ so $\langle Av-A^*v,v\rangle = 0$ doesn't have to be true. Is there a better explanation?

Comment: (1) Even for real numbers $k$ and $r$, it is possible to have $|k|=|r|$ without $k=r$. When $k$ and $r$ can be complex there are even more ways to do this. And we _always_ have $|z|=|\bar z|$ even when $z$ is not real.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see, I just took eigenvectors, how it can be true for all vectors?

Comment: @kuhaku, Are you familiar with the fact that the eigen vectors of normal matrices span the space?

Comment: @ranc no, is this only with normal matrices?

Comment: @kuhaku, the spectral decompositions theorem i know are for normal matrices. Anyways, this is not needed, as you can see by the answer Pedtro Tamaroff gave. (I just wanted to show you another approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal means precisely that $AA^\ast =A^\ast A$. Then $$\langle Av,Av\rangle=\langle v,A^\ast Av\rangle=\langle v,AA^\ast v\rangle=\overline{\langle AA^\ast v,v\rangle}=\overline{\langle A^\ast v,A^\ast v\rangle}$$

This gives the first result. Can you deduce the second from the first?

Comment: Why $\langle Av,Av\rangle=A\langle v,Av\rangle = \langle v,A^\ast Av\rangle$ ?

Comment: @kuhaku The *definition* of the adjoint $A^\ast$ of $A$ is that for any vectors $v,w$, $\langle Av,w\rangle =\langle v,A^\ast w\rangle$. (If my answer didn't clear things up for you, it is not useful to accept it. You can always wait for other answers.)